# HTML5 likebutton doesn't show up on iPad 

Tags: ipad, html, facebook-like

I inserted the HTML5 likebutton code as described on the facebook developers pages into my HTML5 project.

But the likebutton won't show up on the iPad. Only when I use the old iframe version of the code.

Did I overlook something?

The code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Hard to tell, considering we can't see the code.

Comment: Putting `script` after `<div class="fb-like">` may help

Comment: No, that didn't work. I am wondering anyways why no one wonders why this is not working. I mean like everyone is using like buttons on their websites. Or is it just clear that the HTML5 code is simply not working on the iPad and this is why everyone is still using the iframe code? I'm confused.

Comment: I tested [this page](http://jsbin.com/uwixeq) that is just your code in my iPhone and worked. I don't have an iPad, test it in your iPad. If worked then it's something else

Comment: Yes, this code works on the iPhone. But testing the code on the iPad with the latest iOS I see nothing. I cannot image that eather facebook nor Apple is aware of this. What's happening here?

Comment: So then it's a bug with Facebook's like plugin.  You should file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs and report the bug # here for people who might stumble across this StackOverflow question.

Comment: Like buttons work fine on my iPad. Is that your actual whole code, or did you trim out a bunch of other stuff on the page that could be conflicting?

Comment: Really? Which iOS are you running? And no, I didn't change anything on that code. I simply followed the instruction and the rough website code above with the jsbin example doesn't work on my iPad. Btw trying to report a bug at facebook is more complicated than I though. I couldn't figured it out in the last 1/2h. The link @DMCS does only work if you are registered.

Comment: Does the like button on Facebook's documentation for the like button work on your iPad?

Comment: Yes, but I guess it's not the likebutton code you use afterwards. It's just generated code for the preview or the iframe version I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found the like button would not show up on my iPad as I had already liked it. My wife had not and it showed up on hers. Both IOS 10.2.1 both iPad2 Air.

The like button works fine otherwise on an iPhone and desktops...